# Using $.each() with variable

Tags: javascript, jquery, getjson, each

I use $.getJSON to get data from .json file. My .json file's structure looks like the one below

data.json

```
{
    "foo" : {
        "foo1" : {
            "prop1": "foo1's prop1",
            "prop2": "foo1's prop2",
            "prop2": "foo1's prop3",
        },
        ...
    },

    "bar" : {
        "bar1" : {
            "prop1": "bar1's prop1",
            "prop2": "bar1's prop2",
            "prop2": "bar1's prop3",
        },

        ...
    },

    ...

}
```

and my HTML structure

```
     <div class="container">
        <div class="container_header">Choose</div>
        <a href="#" class="container_a" id="foo">Foo</a>
        <a href="#" class="container_a" id="bar">Bar</a>
        ...
    </div>
    <div class="second_container">
        <div class="container_header">Choose</div>
        <div id="get_json">
        </div>
    </div>
```

and .js file that include $.getJSON

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    var $bolumler = $('#get_json');
    $(".container_a").click(function(event){
        var $a_id = $(this).attr('id');
        $.getJSON('data.json', function(data) {
            $bolumler.html('');
            $bolumler.fadeOut(300, function() {
                if ($a_id == "foo") {
                    $.each(data.foo,function(i,data2) {
                        $bolumler.append("<a href='#'>"+data2.prop1+"</a>");
                    });
                } else if ($a_id == "bar") {
                    ...// lots of else if 
                }
            });
            $bolumler.fadeIn(300);
        });
    });
});
```

I want to get data from data.json according to clicked a's id. 
For example, if i click first a -which has id foo-  i want to get foo1,foo2... then i want to use their prop1,pro2,... values. I make it possible with lots of else if statemennt but that was long. Is it possible to use `$.each(variable,function(){});`. I tried these -hopelessly- but they didn't work.

```
                $.each(data.$bk,function(i,data2) {

                var newData = data+"."+$bk;
                $.each(newData,function(i,data2) {
```

Comment: Why are you fetching the same document multiple times, is there any particular reason you wouldn't want to load data into an object that can be later fetched from?

Comment: @MatthewBucci I'm new to AJAX. I didn't know that I can assing document to a variable. I thougth it just connects to .json file and you get the particular information that you want from that file.

Comment: anonymous functions in javascript inherit their parent scope. This means that if in document.ready you place var result = {}. you can then say result= data in the callback for getJSON and it will be assigned. Then in your click callback you can say if(!result){getJSON} else {$bolumer.html(result[$a_id])}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use this to get objects as you want..

```
data["foo"]
```

or in your case

```
data[$a_id]
```

you can do this also in the $.each